# Loop to copy column in one sheet to a table in a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to create a macro that copies a single column of data from the '**Home**' tab to a table in a different tab. Currently, my macro copies the column (one cell at a time because the column range is variable) to the table in '**Sheet 1**'. My problem is the macro only works one time because I can't figure out how to expand the columns to the right in the table every time I run the macro. Does that make sense?

You might be asking, why not just copy/paste the data in the table manually? I have multiple tabs and I am going to create multiple macros - one for each tab. Ideally I will run the macro based off of the information pasted in the single column in the '**Home**' tab and it will paste as a new column to the table in the tab that it's going to.

```
Sub Sheet3()

Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

Set NewData = Sheets("Home")
Set Sheet3 = Sheets("Question 3")

lastRow = NewData.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To lastRow
    'test if cell is empty
    If NewData.Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
        Sheet3.Range("D" & i - 2).Value = NewData.Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem Dave. Unfortunately, the data is still copying on top of column D in the table in Sheet 3. I will always want to pull from column B in the 'Home' tab. The 'Question 3' tab defined as 'Sheet3' above has the table that I am trying to expand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Sheet3` is the internal name of one of your worksheets. No matter what's on the tab, `Sheet3` will always refer to the 3rd sheet in the collection.

My test workbook only has 1 sheet in it, but you can see it in the screen shot of the Project Explorer:
[image]

You can see that even though I've renamed the tab "test", internally it can still be referenced in code as `Sheet1`.

The simple thing to do is change this line
`Set Sheet3 = Sheets("Question 3")`
to something like this
`Set otherSheet = Sheets("Question 3")`

However, I'd recommend the following as the solution to the issue of "*I have multiple tabs and I am going to create multiple macros - one for each tab.*" Instead of writing one proc dedicated to each sheet (or sheet pair), write one procedure that can be called multiple times, like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CopyCells(ByVal sourceSheet As Worksheet, ByVal destSheet As Worksheet, _
                      ByVal sourceCol As Long, ByVal destCol As Long)

  Dim lastRow As Long
  With sourceSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  Dim i As Long
  For i = 6 To lastRow
    If sourceSheet.Cells(i, sourceCol).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
      destSheet.Cells(i - 2, destCol).Value2 = sourceSheet.Cells(i, sourceCol).Value2
    End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

Now, you can write one line of code to copy the cells from sheet to sheet, and have multiple calls to `CopyCells`, one for each sheet. For example:

```
CopyCells(myWB.Sheets("Home"), myWB.Sheets("Question 3"), 2, 4)
CopyCells(myWB.Sheets("Home"), myWB.Sheets("Question 2"), 3, 7)
'etc...
```

This, of course, presumes that you always want the destination to be 2 rows higher than the source and that the source data always begins on row 6. If either of those are variable, then you can add them as parameters, as well.

Comment: FreeMan thanks for your help this is great stuff. I created a single macro to try out your call suggestion and it is erroring out 'Object required'. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a way I can show you my current coding? This is my first ever question posted on StackOverflow.

Comment: @BrandonM. Yes, edit your original post and include whatever additional information you need to in there. Note - ADD the new code, don't replace the original code, otherwise the question won't make any sense to those who may be coming along later looking for the answer to the same type of question.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code replace column D in this line:

> `Sheet3.Range("D" & i - 2).Value = NewData.Range("B" & i).Value`

withe the next column you want to copy to:

> `Sheet3.Range("E" & i - 2).Value = NewData.Range("B" & i).Value`

Or determine the first empty column dynamically:

```
lastCol = Sheet3.Cells(1, Sheet3.Columns.Count).xlEnd(xlToLeft).Column
```

Then the copy line will become:

```
Sheet3.Cells(i - 2, lastCol).Value = NewData.Range("B" & i).Value
```

---

.

The code bellow iterates trough all sheets, and if it finds sheets named "Home*" it will copy columns B from each Home sheet to the end of the table

The table will resize itself (horizontally and vertically) as needed

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyColFromHome()
    Const BCOL = "B"
    Const FR = 6

    Dim wsQ As Worksheet:       Set wsQ = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Question 3")
    Dim tbl As ListObject:      Set tbl = wsQ.ListObjects("Table1") 'Update table name

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, tblLc As Long, srcCol As Range, dstCol As Range

    tblLc = tbl.ListColumns.Count + 1               'First empty table column

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets          'Iterate all sheets
        If LCase(Left(ws.Name, 4)) = "home" Then    'If sheet name starts with "home"

            lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, BCOL).End(xlUp).Row    'Get last row in ws.colB

            If lr > FR Then     'If there are enough rows to copy from ws.colB

                wsQ.Cells(1, tblLc).Value2 = ws.Name    'Header of the new table column

                Set srcCol = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FR, BCOL), ws.Cells(lr, BCOL))
                Set dstCol = wsQ.Range(wsQ.Cells(FR - 2, tblLc), wsQ.Cells(lr - 2, tblLc))

                dstCol.Formula = srcCol.Formula         'Copy data to last column of table
                dstCol.ColumnWidth = dstCol.Offset(, -1).ColumnWidth    'Resize column

                tblLc = tblLc + 1   'Move to the next empty table column
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

---

My test file has 3 Home sheets, and one sheet "Question 3":

Sheet Home

[image: SheetHome]

Sheet Home1

[image: SheetHome1]

Sheet Home2

[image: SheetHome3]

Sheet "Question 3" (with the table)

[image: SheetQuestion3]

After the first iteration through the loop:

[image: Iter1]

After the 3rd iteration (Home2 doesn't have enough rows)

[image: Iter3]